# Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module does not exist or is not installed

Tags: theming

I get this error on my site

> Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module
>   does not exist or is not installed. in
>   Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->getExtensionInfo() (line 346 of
>   ...core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php).

This error is happening in shared hosting server.

```
  public function getExtensionInfo($extension_name) {
$all_info = $this->getAllInstalledInfo();
if (isset($all_info[$extension_name])) {
  return $all_info[$extension_name];
}
throw new UnknownExtensionException("The {$this->type} $extension_name does not exist or is not installed."); // line 346
```

}

I have been searching online and found lot of discussions but I could not fix it. How can I fix the error?

Php: 7.0
Drupal: 8

Comment: It is obvious that the extension name is an empty string. You need a full error message with stack trace to find out which code is calling the method with a null string. It's unlikely it's a bug in the code itself, but it could point you to the database or config entry which contains the null string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have agree with @4k4 you can fix this with database

If your module have been deleted from the system use this query

```
delete from `key_value` where collection = 'system.schema' and name = '$extension_name';
```

for example:

```
delete from `key_value` where collection = 'system.schema' and name = 'config_tools';
delete from `key_value` where collection = 'system.schema' and name = 'git_config';
```

Comment: How am I supposed to know what to delete?  I do a select * and everything looks ok, it  seems to me my issue is something else

Comment: @JonWeinraub from  4k4 comment  - You need a full error message with stack trace to find out which code is calling the method with a null string. In my case i have made additional debug to get module name and than run this commands

Comment: all the text afterwards is too long for a comment so i suspect I should ask my own question but don't want it flagged for duplicate

Answer (score 5):

I had the error still appearing no matter what.

> Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module
> twig_food does not exist.

Finaly i found this command working:

```
drush cdel core.extension module.twig_food
```

Comment: This is a different issue. OP's issue has no module name.